# Can't get the right result in condition

Tags: javascript

I can't get theright result, "Weird" on stdin, 18 and 20. Everything looks good to me, however something must be off.

```js
if (N % 2 == 1) {
    console.log("Weird");
}
else if ((N % 2 == 0) && (2 >= N <= 5)) {
    console.log("Not Weird");
}
else if ((N % 2 == 0) && (5 <= N <= 20)) {
    console.log("Weird");
}
else if ((N % 2 == 0) && (N > 20)) {
    console.log("Not Weird");
}
else {
    console.log("Weird");
}
```

```
'use strict';

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding('utf-8');

let inputString = '';
let currentLine = 0;

process.stdin.on('data', inputStdin => {
    inputString += inputStdin;
});

process.stdin.on('end', _ => {
    inputString = inputString.replace(/\s*$/, '')
        .split('\n')
        .map(str => str.replace(/\s*$/, ''));

    main();
});

function readLine() {
    return inputString[currentLine++];
}



function main() {
    const N = parseInt(readLine(), 10);
    if (N%2==1) {
        console.log("Weird");
    }
    else if ((N % 2 == 0) && (2 >= N <= 5)) {
        console.log("Not Weird");
    }
    else if ((N % 2 == 0) && (5 <= N && N <= 20)) {
        console.log("Weird");
    }
    else if ((N % 2 == 0) && (N > 20)) {
        console.log("Not Weird");
    }
                    else{
                    console.log("Weird");
                }
            }
```

I ve added the whole code. In the main function, in the second else if  condition, there seems to be the problem. When n is given 18 or 20, I can not get the right output which should be "Weird"

Comment: You need to be way more clear dude. What is the exact input you are putting in? How are  you creating N? You have 3 different places that say "weird" which one are you talking about? You are not being clear enough.

Comment: what is the value of `N`?

Comment: I am sure a good linter built into your IDE would have complained about the comparison.

Comment: I ve tried to be more clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can't be doing two conditions in the same time

```
if (5<=N<=20) {}
```

Will evaluate 5<=N first which produces either true/false which are when compared to numbers will evaluate to (1/0) respectively. Then the second part ( <= 20) will be evaluated.

Combine two conditions only with AND / OR operators

```
if (5 <= N && N <= 20) {}
```

This will solve your problem.